# Excel VBA removing a row if it contains a letter

Tags: vba, excel

So i have a set of data that has various numbers with letters at the end
in example would be

```
233423528535A
3453453453945
234234235532C
3453453455345
234234238964D
3453453453234
656234234534G
346364634636Z
6456456456452
3453453453242
234234234234X
```

I want to create a vba script that if a row in this column contains a letter it can be deleted. 
I tried using an excel function however excel functions dont allow rows to be deleted.

Comment: Are teh cells true numbers and text> Are they both right and left aligned in their cells? Are they the General format or formatted as Text?

Comment: Right(<string> , 1)  where string is your Cell.Value

Comment: They are left aligned and general text, as well not all of them have the same amount of cahracters in the cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this short sub to remove all rows containing non-numeric values in column A.

```
Sub noAlphas()
    On Error Resume Next
    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey I have a new set of data but it's deleting everything!
the data is is as such
`376600693A
417243292C2
371785392
373608918A
369780072
363643189
383600770
384029360
365219868M
365216930M
381766640
368804162
363889817
370021985
382152282
306306377
423549718
372211916
296921199
367601665
601615781
367806642A
373881174`

whenver I enter that it deletes everything, its left aligned and general text but its deleting everything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
 Sub RemLetterRows()
    Dim DelRow As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A") ' Write your sheetname between "" & column
        On Error Resume Next
          Set DelRow = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors + xlTextValues + xlLogical)
          DelRow.EntireRow.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    End Sub
```

Regards 
Daniel

Comment: Good point about stacking up all of the possible non-numeric [xlCellTypeConstants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) xllSpecialCellsValue possibilities for [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped actually we have almost the same soltuion =) but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the cells are formatted as text, try to convert them and delete based on the type mismatch error:

Sub noAlphas()
    On Error Resume Next

```
For i = 11 To 1 Step -1
    j = CLng(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If Err.Number = 13 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

Next
```

End Sub